# New deployed Azure web app is returning 404 Error code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal, cicd

I have deployed an ASP.NET Core Web API project using terraform. I can see it has been deployed successfully and the web app service is running. When I browse to the link it returns 404. I was wondering if i can get help  on identifying why I am getting 404 error code when it has deployed successfully. I am using the FREE Azure subscription in case it makes difference.
Link: https://tigrinyadictionary-api.azurewebsites.net/
[image]

Comment: Hello @kiflay, Any update on this.!? , If my answer is helpful for you, you can  accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you:)

Answer (score 9):

Since there is no startup page on web api project, that is why you are getting this error. Let me explain. Ihave created default asp.net web api having weatherforecast. If you run that in your local environment, you will face the same issue of "Resoure not found" as shown in below image.

**404 Error**
[image]

Now, if I just append the weatherforecast at the end of the URL, it will start working as shown below:-

**Data is shown**
[image]

Above is true for the Azure Deployment as well. I have deployed the same web api on azure, as azure app service and it is showing 404 as shown below:-

**Again 404**

[image]

Now add weatherforecast at end and it will start working and 404 will gone as shown below:-

**Data is shown**:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in my environment and also getting the **HTTP 404 error** in my ASP. NET Core Web API project after deploy to azure which working fine locally, and then trying some configuration as below,

Error page : -
[image]

**SOLUTION -1**:
In our ASP. net core web API project there was no `web.config` file, You can try to add one  config file in VS . Go to root of your project>Add>new item>search for config >web configuration file .

[image]

And below is the example of code which  you can add your own URI and save it in `web.config` file .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\yourURI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

[image]

**SOLUTION-2**:
Make sure that your url in the browser is correct. In some scenario we need to add. Then try to run the Web application . & this is working fine for me . For example:

> https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxx
> or,
> azureAPIurl/api/controllername

[image]

For more information please refer this SO Thread :  [ASP.NET Core Web API runs locally but not on Azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515508/asp-net-core-web-api-runs-locally-but-not-on-azure-app-service) & Dev Blogs: [404 response code caused by App Services](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/404-response-code-caused-by-app-services-alwayson-feature/)