# .NET WebAPI works well on localhost, but doesn't work on Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, webapi

[image]
I uploaded my api to azure. I know that you shouldn't direct to the below shown url because there is no webpage. But all api requests are not working

[image]

It seems as though everything was published fine but is not working. What could be the problem?

Comment: What kind of response/response code you are getting when calling API ?

Comment: Could you please let us know have you tried with `https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxx`

Comment: Please provide more details on the error you are getting. Currently it's hard to guess what what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your webapi to azure and get it to work make sure that you have following workaround :

- I have created .Net webAPI and here make sure that you have following in your `program.cs`
  `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`
  [image]
- And after deploy to azure App service make sure that you have the following configuration ,In my case i have created **web+Database** in portal and deploy my **webAPI**

[image]

- And here are the output for reference ,If we use the default url without calling any API it will not working , followed by this you can call your API to get it work https://yoursolution.azurewebsites.net/yourapi

[image]

For more information please refer the below links :

- MS DOC:[Publish an ASP.NET Core web API to Azure API Management with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- Blog: [How to deploy asp.net core web api to azure app service](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/azure/deploy-asp.net-core-web-api-to-azure-app-service/)
- SO THREAD:[ASP.NET Core Web API runs locally but not on Azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515508/asp-net-core-web-api-runs-locally-but-not-on-azure-app-service?noredirect=1&lq=1)